# pf NAT for local originated traffic

Tags: macos, nat, osx-yosemite

I am trying to proxy 22 traffic, originated from my machine, so it will be proxied / forwarded to a remote server. This was very easy with ipfw but Yosemite has only pf ....

Did anyone found out how to rdr on local (originated from the machine) traffic on OSX Yosemite ?

this is not working !

```
# Custom pf Rules
#######################################
# target_ip is the ip of which I would like traffic to be proxied  
target_ip = "10.0.0.2” 
# porxy_ip is the proxy address 
porxy_ip = "192.168.1.100”


rdr pass log on lo0 proto tcp from en0 to $target_ip port 80 -> $porxy_ip port 8080

pass out on en0 route-to lo0 inet proto tcp from en0 to $target_ip port 80 keep state

# End
```

any advise ?